# log into magento remotely

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a suite of apps, its all distributed - on different subdomains, different boxes, etc..  when I log into one web app, I would like to automatically log the user into our store (magento) as well.  Is this possible to do?

Since the applications are not on the same machine, I don't have access to the Mage files, so I cannot pragmatically log the user in.  I looked into magento's oauth, but I don't want the user to keep confirming to login, since its all supposed to be one seamless experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cURL post request with the correct Magento admin credentials from your server, save the cookie and store it in the users browser through a redirect or refresh, and then redirect the user to the Magento admin page. The cookie should match the admin session and the user should be logged in.

There are a couple Magento settings that could prevent this, like IP checking or user-agent checking and what-not, but they should be off by default.

Answer (score 0):

We have one client that requires us to do something really like this. The client has lots of legacy applications.

What we did was, we redirected the user to the Magento application with URL query strings below:

- email - email to auto login
- url_validation - the Magento will check this URL if we really allowed to login the email. This URL should be valid only on one request for security.

see sample controller code below:

```
<?php

class Example_Customerlogin_CustomerloginController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    protected $_whitelistedDomain = array(
        'example.local.com',
    );

    public function generateAction()
    {
        // http://example.local.com/customerlogin/customerlogin/generate
        $url_validation = 'http://example.local.com/customerlogin/customerlogin/validate?'.http_build_query(array(
                'email' => 'sample@example.com',
                'permission_code' => '6226f7cbe59e99a90b5cef6f94f966fd',
            ));
        echo 'http://example.local.com/customerlogin/customerlogin/autologin/?email=sample@example.com&url_validation='.urlencode($url_validation);
        die();
    }

    public function validateAction()
    {
        // this is a sample url. You should implement this on third party application
        // this should expired once visited
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $permission_code = $_GET['permission_code'];
        if ($email == 'sample@example.com' && $permission_code == '6226f7cbe59e99a90b5cef6f94f966fd') {
            echo 'ok';
            die();
        }

        echo 'false';
        die();
    }

    public function autologinAction()
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $email = $request->getParam('email');
        $url_validation = $request->getParam('url_validation');
        $website_code = $request->getParam('website_code', Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView()->getWebsite()->getCode());
        $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_code);

        if (!$website) {
            $session->addMessage('Website failed.');
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        }

        if (!$this->_validateLogin($url_validation)) {
            $session->addMessage('Failed to auto login.');
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        }

        $customer->website_id = $website->getId();
        $customer->setStore($website->getDefaultStore());
        $customer->loadByEmail('atilloregner@gmail.com');
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

        $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
    }

    private function _validateLogin($url_validation)
    {
        // check if belongs to whitelisted domains
        $url = parse_url($url_validation);
        if (!($url && in_array($url['host'], $this->_whitelistedDomain))) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = file_get_contents($url_validation);

        if (trim($return) === 'ok') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

There might be another solution but this solution works really well for us.